# Using Data Preview CKAN

Tags: ckan

I am running CKAN v 2.5 installed using the package installation with the datastore and datapusher configured, but I am seeing this when I try to preview the data. Nothing suspicious is in the logs.

[rendering datatable issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43n5Y.png)

Comment: What is displayed when you edit the resource and look under the Datastore tab? My first guess is that it hasn't loaded successfully into the datastore and the viewer is trying to show the file (which has sone issues like the one you show in the image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I have seen odd things like this when there are blank columns in the uploaded data, or perhaps a mixed data field (with some cells numbers, others text).

What file format did you upload?   Have you tried with a very small and simple test file to see if that works?  Have you tried uploading the file to the demo ckan instance (http://demo.ckan.org/) to see if the file works OK there?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the problem was here, but it was something with the data.  Simplifying the file and loading the data to the demo instance was helpful. Thanks,